# How to detect non-english characters in a text file?

Tags: regex, bash, awk, ascii

I was wondering if there was an awk/sed regex that I can use to detect any lines that contain non-english characters, for example:

```
あと１つのスマッシュが見つからへん…もう寝よう
ความหวังดีของคนเรา สุดท้าย
Το θερμόμετρο χτυπάει
LA #MACIF a félicité #DotYou pour le site http://www.roulonspourlavenir.com , un petit compliment dans un monde de brutos... c'est bon ça!!
```

but since they are twitter posts, I need to keep lines with links, @ symbols, therefore I believe I am looking to detect any non-ascii characters?

Thanks for any help,

Tomek

Comment: What is your end goal with this?

Comment: Define "English" characters.  The question makes no sense.  Are you merely trying to exclude code points above 0177?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
/[^a-z0-9]/i
```